# How to use cyrillic in python IMAP search?

Tags: python, imap, gmail-imap, imaplib, cyrillic

How can I use cyrillic symbols in imapObj.search()?
I am doing  the following IMAP search:

```
imapObj.search("utf-8", "(SUBJECT '%s')" % u"кириллица".encode("utf-8"))
```

And it doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding `u` in front of "(SUBJECT '%s')".

Comment: I have tried this way and it doesn't work(

Comment: And what's the error you get?

Comment: like this "'ascii' codec can't encode character"

Comment: Try just `u"(SUBJECT {0})".format(u"кириллица")` (btw using `%` for string formatting considered a little bit discouraged)

Comment: now I have this error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 36-44: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: If I try to do it this way u"(SUBJECT '{0}')".format(u"кириллица").encode('utf-8'). I have a "imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']" error.

Comment: Well, at least unicode error is resolved. As for IMAP - I'm afraid I'm not proficient in the area, so won't be able to help.

Comment: Prefixing with "CHARSET utf8" would help; the full command is then search charset utf8 subject "кириллиц".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes around your subject, not single quotes:

```
imapObj.search("utf-8", '(SUBJECT "%s")' % u"кириллица".encode("utf-8"))
# or this also does the same:
imapObj.search("utf-8", 'SUBJECT', u"кириллица".encode("utf-8"))
```

the rest should be OK - if your criterion contains characters outside the ascii range encoding it from unicode to the specified charset like you do is correct.

Comment: imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']